# Save objects into separate blender files

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is fairly simple but I've found no way to do it. I want to store each object in a scene into a separate blender file. Here's my code:

```
import bpy
import os
destination_folder = "destination_folder"

for idx, obj in enumerate(bpy.data.objects):
    ctx = bpy.context.copy()
    ctx['selected_objects'] = obj
    file_name = 'file_number' + str(idx) + '.blend'
    bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(ctx, filepath=os.path.join(destination_folder, file_name))
```

The problem is that the operator bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile() doesn't have the flag "selected" as many others wm operators do. Any idea? I think context override is a good idea but I'm struggling to do it

Comment: Is your approach above getting isolated objects?  Are you getting partially successful results?  Why is the ["selected"] useful?

Comment: Do you have collections of objects ?  Parent Child relationships in your data?

Comment: How many files need to be transformed?  How many objects need to be isolated?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger No, my approach it's not working. ctx["selected"] is useful for context override (https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html). Yes, I may have parentship in my files. The file is unique but It potentially contains a large number of files to be isolated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving multiple objects as separate Blender's files can be done by using BlendDataLibraries (https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html)

```
import bpy
import os
destination_folder = "destination_folder"

for idx, obj in enumerate(bpy.data.objects):
    ctx = bpy.context.copy()
    ctx['selected_objects'] = obj
    filename = 'file_number' + str(idx) + '.blend'
    filepath = os.path.join(destination_folder, filename)
    bpy.data.libraries.write(filepath, set(ctx['selected_objects']), fake_user=True)
```

This code snippet will save the object in a blender's file. To load then the data in the visible user interface a second snippet can be run on the opened saved file:

```
collection = bpy.data.collections.new('collection')
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
  collection.objects.link(obj) #link object to collection
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(collection) #add collection
```

This second script creates a collection and loads all the objects in the Blender file into it and (in some sense) sets it visible/active

Answer (score -2):

**File Append**

You might consider a script ..

- Opens a new Blender file or reuses a single file in RAM...
- [File Append] (or Link) from the existing large Blender
  File.  [File Append] is more tested than anything you will write in the next N months. N ∈ {3,4,5 ...}
- Saves the file to hard disk or similar, with a unique path name.  This implies a Python [for] as in the original question.

---

- Blender can take command line
  Python script name to (enumerate) and select a given object for the
  command [File Append]
- The Python script needs an enumeration to Append a different object each time.
- The Python script can Append, File Save, Destroy All Objects ,to reduce Object Count to Zero for the next iteration.  You will need a Python list to record your desired [Append] actions.

---

Perhaps an option

- An OS Script (Linux Windows Mac) to Launch Blender (this may be optional to reduce exectution time)

Comment: No, opening a new file each time is way too expensive. This approach for sure would work, but the running time will exceed by far my requirements