# object list is not iterable and save directly in stl files

Tags: objects

I'm a new blender user and I am probably missing something simple but trying this script

[Save objects into separate blender files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/188113/save-objects-into-separate-blender-files/208082?noredirect=1#comment351052_208082)

to save multiple objects as separate Blender's files I get an error because it doesn't seem possible to iterate on a list of objects. Any suggestions? thanks

found bundled python: /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.91/python Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Text", line 10, in TypeError: 'Object' object is not iterable

ps is there an option to save directly in stl files?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save existing objects in separate stl files with this statement

my_filepath = bpy.path.abspath(' //my_directory/ ')

bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath = my_filepath, batch_mode = 'OBJECT')